# Android Back camera doesn't work..Front camera only works

Tags: android, camera

I am tring to build android camera app..I have problem that the rear camera not working..But the front camera working perfectly

My code for fromt camera (Working):

```
  if (mCamera == null) {
        try {

            mCamera = Camera.open(1);
            Log.d(TAG, "Camera working");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Camera Exception");
        }

    }
```

When I change 1 to 0.. It's throw an Exception (fail to connect to camera service : camera 0) My code:

```
 if (mCamera == null) {
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open(0);
            Log.d(TAG, "Camera working");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Camera Exception");
        }
    }
```

I tried many solution..But all of them failed..Hope to get an answer..Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not assume that 0 and 1 are rear-facing and front-facing, respectively. Beyond that, try rebooting your device. Sometimes, if an app fails to release the `Camera` properly, the camera cannot be used by anyone until the device is rebooted.

Comment: @CommonsWare It doesn't work..After rebooting I had the same Exception only with Front camera..I tried another device but the it's throw the same exception..thanks